# How to add error message to commerce checkout form element?

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I created a simple module to add additional validations to the commerce checkout module checkout form but I don't know how to add an error message to the storage array so it can behave like any error message from the commerce checkout module.

Can you help me with this ?